# why does rewriteBatchedStatements default to false for mysql connector/j?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

The mysql jdbc driver [has a property called rewriteBatchedStatements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) that, when set to true can [improve batch inserts significantly](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/16/what-you-didnt-know-about-jdbc-batch/), but has to be explicitly turned on.

I've had to do this for multiple projects now, and couldnt find any good reason why I must manually turn this on.

Why is this not the default?

Comment: This should probably something you should ask in a ticket to MySQL, but if I had to guess, maybe some versions don't support it, or it changes some semantics of statements, or maybe it has a hidden cost, or maybe it doesn't comply with some of the JDBC requirements of batch execution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The connection property rewriteBatchedStatements provides a non-JDBC compliant feature. Not all statements can be re-written and it may held unexpected results. Particularly with regard to handling errors and returning update counts.

Also note that rewriteBatchedStatements can modify the original SQL string beyond a simple concatenation of queries which, in many cases, is not expected or desirable.

For those reasons, and many others, this property is false by default.